# How to use the tabto package inside addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, tabto

I need to add an absolute horizontal spacing inside `\addcontentsline`, but unfortunately the function `\tabto` don't seems to be supported.

So I need to do that:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{SomeText \tabto{4cm} SomeOtherText}
```

But the compiler crash with the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

I must add that the function \tabto works normaly in other situations.

Comment: Use `\protect` before `\tabto` inside the argument of `\addcontentsline`: `... \protect\tabto{4cm} ...`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !